# Custom location text for GitHub organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

How do I set a custom text for the location field of my GitHub organization? Such as the one [below](https://github.com/github):

[image]

Under the settings of the organization, I can only find a drop-down menu that lets me select a country.

[image]

Comment: And https://github.com/Homebrew shows `GitHub` as its location, but that isn't a dropdown selection.

Comment: Yep, I guess this feature was removed. An earlier organization that I created had a location which now isn't present in the dropdown. I suppose it was most probably a text field earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late to the game, but this solved my issue!

For organizations:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer GH_PAT_HERE" -d '{"location":"YOUR CUSTOM LOCATION"}' https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG_NAME
```

Additionally for users:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer GH_PAT_HERE" -d '{"location":"YOUR CUSTOM LOCATION"}' https://api.github.com/user
```

Credit: https://github.community/t/setting-custom-location-for-github-free-organizations/193506/2

Comment: If this doesn't work, try removing "bearer". Still didn't work for me, but it did get past the "Bad credentials" error.

Comment: to enhance this answer there is an open discussion to integrate it in the web ui of github : https://github.com/community/community/discussions/15762

Answer (score 5):

The previous method didn't work for me in 2022, but I found something much simpler.

First, go to your organisation settings.

Next, open DevTools and find the element with ID organization_profile_location. Change its value to whatever you like.

Finally, press "Update profile" to save your changes. Use this method at your own risk, as it is not official.

According to Teddy van Jerry (someone in the comments), this isn't valid for requesting publisher verification.

Comment: Seems to be a neat trick

Comment: Yep, it works, but that is not valid for requesting publisher verification.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to get the **Text Field** back.

---

First, search for this in the DevTools Elements page.

```html
<input class="js-org-location-input-hidden" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="organization[profile_location]" id="organization_profile_location">
```

And replace it with this:

```html
<input class="js-org-location-input-hidden" autocomplete="off" name="organization[profile_location]" id="organization_profile_location">
```

The result is there will be a text field.
[How it looks with the text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mDdv.png)

---

> Remember, this is glitchy a lot. The dropdown will appear sometimes while typing.